Timeline corruption PostgreSQL
I have this error, and I don't know how to fix it correctly. I saw people doing pg_basebackup everytime it happens. There is any better way?
2024-08-27 12:27:41.521 CEST [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.12 (Debian 14.12-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
2024-08-27 12:27:41.526 CEST [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2024-08-27 12:27:41.535 CEST [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2024-08-27 12:27:41.555 CEST [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2024-08-27 12:27:41.566 CEST [27] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-08-27 12:27:08 CEST
2024-08-27 12:27:41.570 CEST [27] LOG:  entering standby mode
2024-08-27 12:27:41.570 CEST [27] FATAL:  requested timeline 7 is not a child of this server's history
2024-08-27 12:27:41.570 CEST [27] DETAIL:  Latest checkpoint is at 2C/8B000028 on timeline 6, but in the history of the requested timeline, the server forked off from that timeline at 2C/7C000060.
2024-08-27 12:27:41.575 CEST [1] LOG:  startup process (PID 27) exited with exit code 1
2024-08-27 12:27:41.576 CEST [1] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2024-08-27 12:27:41.712 CEST [1] LOG:  database system is shut down


Postgres 14 is old (granted, 14.12 is a recent point-release) - is there a reason you can't update to 16.4? (or 14.13?)

@Dai Because I'm using in my job, and they are using this version.

Is there a 00000007.history file in pg_wal or the WAL archive?

Either don't request restoration to timeline 7, or don't use timeline 6 as the base backup for the restoration attempt.  We have no way of knowing which of these things is the correct option based on the information provided.
